# Fastest way to check in python if a file exists and get its path in a very wide tree of subdirectories

Tags: python, directory, find, binary-search-tree, directory-structure

So my problem is I have a directory with over 1000 subdirectories and I want the most efficient way to check if a certain file is in them. Is there a way to do this without stepping through each directory until I find it? I would prefer a pythonic way of doing this but anything that can be run through os.system would be acceptable as long as it is efficient. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in http://bugs.python.org/issue11406 walk is slower than it should be, community came up with an alternative of course.

Assuming that by `fastest` you mean run time, you should use `scandir`:
https://github.com/benhoyt/scandir/#readme